# Can we send an email to the specific users once after the report is generated in Infor syteline erp?

Tags: erp

Can we send an email to the specific users whenever the order verification report is generated with the report output as an attachment in Infor syteline erp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Create a stored procedure to send an email using SQL DB mail statement by passing the BGTask number as an input parameter. BGTask number will helps to understand whether report is generated or not.

Comment: How do we understand the report is generated using BGTask number?

Comment: You can check the BGTask completeion status on the table and add wait for delay inside a while loop until completion status column is updated. Once the column is updated (which means report is generated) skip the loop and attach the report.